# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression how I Use my Type REferencesType

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In the base document, I have a field that inherits from the `BaseReferencesType` class. It's virtual, why can't I do anything when I'm busy.
This field which i want get

```cs
public virtual ReferenceType ReferenceType { get; }
```

And my script:

```cs
var document = await _context.BaseDocuments
    .Where(x => bulkPostDto.Documents.Contains(x.ReferenceType) &&
                x.CreatedDate.Value.Date >= bulkPostDto.Start.Date &&
                x.CreatedDate.Value.Date <= bulkPostDto.Finish)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DocumentDate)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Now my problem looks like this@

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The expression 'x.ReferenceType' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.%27)

I transferred data through the service, but received an error

```json
{
  "documents": [
    0
  ],
  "start": "2022-01-05T13:16:31.289Z",
  "finish": "2023-01-05T13:16:31.289Z",
  "repostAlreadyPosted": true,
  "postUnposted": true,
  "interruptWhenPostFailed": true
}
```

Photo class ReferenceType
[image]

Comment: Is object static in your virtual declaration?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members?force_isolation=true  Error is implying you need an instance of the object.  I think type should be static.

Comment: I have a virtual field, do I need to wrap it in the interface?

Comment: You have a virtual class, with properties (fields).  An interface is just a tools to filter properties of a class. Your query needs to get access to the data and it doesn't matter if it comes from an interface or directly from the class object.  You are looking for the data in the Entity object _context.  The type values are in the class  ReferenceType

Comment: I added a photo, a class, we will follow this class for BaseDocument, from it we will receive data for processing

Comment: The data is in the instance of the class.  Are you referencing the type or the instances.  It is better to make the Class names starting with capital letters and instances with lowercase so you do not confuse the two.

Comment: the problem was in virtual fields, I decided to create an ordinary field and initialize it through the constructor